# Use variable instead of a string with Interactive Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying to create Notifications with more than one option for the user to choose. I have these working just fine.

However I don't want to use a hardcoded String for the title of the option buttons. Instead I want to use a variable (which is a String), but it doesn't work!

```
let word1Action = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    word1Action.identifier = "word"
    word1Action.title = "word"
    word1Action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    word1Action.destructive = false
    word1Action.authenticationRequired = false
```

In the above code, "word" shows in the Notification button.

```
let word2Action = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    word2Action.identifier = "word_1"
    word2Action.title = "0\(word_1)"
    word2Action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    word2Action.destructive = false
    word2Action.authenticationRequired = false
```

In the above code, only the "0" shows on the Notification button.

```
let word3Action = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    word3Action.identifier = "word_2"
    word3Action.title = word_2
    word3Action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    word3Action.destructive = false
    word3Action.authenticationRequired = false
```

In the above code, the Notification button is blank.

So why is it that only a basic String works?

I have verified that the variable that I am using is in fact a String and I am getting no other errors, just blank notifications.

Any thoughts? Is this an iOS restriction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I feel silly. I had the above code posted in AppDelegate under

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

And since the variables I was trying to access were Global and had not been initiated yet they were showing up blank.

Guess I needed one more cup of coffee today. ;-)